# telegramBOT. Вывод определенных полей с Message

Tags: python, telegram-bot

есть сообщение от Бота:

```
print(message)
{'content_type': 'text', 'id': 1797, 'message_id': 1797, 'from_user': {'id': 51665305, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Smart', 'username': 'Smart_777', 'last_name': None, 'language_code': 'en', 'can_join_groups': None, 'can_read_all_group_messages': None, 'supports_inline_queries': None},  'text': '1001'}}
```

Но как из этих сообщений вывести нужные данные. Например: `username`, `first_name`, `id`, `text` и тогдали

Comment: Вы имеете в виду "_Как вывести значение из вложенного словаря_"?

Comment: Ну когда функцию пишете для телеграмм бота, потом же можете сделать print(message) и показывает все сообщение. Из этих сообщений хочу вывести нужные данные только.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, `id` можно вывести так:

```
print(message['from_user']['id'])
```

Или так (это вы встретите везде):

```
print(message.from_user.id)
```

(*короче*)

**Вывод:**

```
51665305
```

И заменяйте `['id']` на `['username']`, `['first_name']`, `['text']` и "*тогдали*" :))

Comment: Помог ли ответ?

Comment: Да, наконец то! ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: @Handsome_777 не за что :))